# How to install the USB Token MS-IDProtect

Tags: apt, usb, smartcard

The USB Token is a cryptographic device used to generate and protect the digital certificate issued by a licensed certification.

This device can be used on any PC that has a USB port.

Answer (score 1):

A method to achieve its operation is as follows:

1. Get the middleware that must be provided by the distributor of the token.

   Or download it from:

   http://www.aladdin-rd.ru/support/downloads/get?ID=39875

   The archive `jacarta_pki_linux.zip` contains deb and rpm versions.

   For Ubuntu and Debian the files are:

   - `idprotectclient_637.03-0_amd64.deb` - 64 bits
   - `idprotectclient_637.03-0_i386.deb` - 32 bits

   These files, once the file jacarta_pki_linux.zip unzipped, are found in /Deb.
2. Install required dependencies, opening a terminal and running on it:

   ```
   exec sudo -i
   apt-get update
   apt-get dist-upgrade
   apt-get install --reinstall coolkey gdebi libasedrive-usb libusb-1.0-0 libusb-1.0-0-dev libpcsclite-dev libpcslite1 libreadline6 libreadline6-dev libreadline-dev pcscd pcsc-tools opensc pinentry-gtk2
   ```
3. Install by gdebi our distribution corresponding to 32 or 64 bits file:

   - `idprotectclient_637.03-0_amd64.deb` - 64 bits, or
   - `idprotectclient_637.03-0_i386.deb` - 32 bits

4- Restart, they appear on the desktop launchers for:
`IDProtecT Manager` and `IDProtect PINTool`. And can be recognized and used the token

[Source](http://www.ubuntu-es.org/node/190976#.V_rdz5Cw24o)